# Is SparkEnv created after the creation of SparkSession in Spark 2?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark 1.6, a `SparkEnv` is automatically created after the creating a new `SparkContext` object.

In Spark 2.0, `SparkSession` was introduced as the entry point to Spark SQL.

Is `SparkEnv` created automatically after the creation of SparkSession in Spark 2?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `SparkEnv`, `SparkConf` and `SparkContext` are all automatically created when `SparkSession` is created (and that's why corresponding code in Spark SQL is more high-level and hopefully less error-prone).

`SparkEnv` is a part of Spark runtime infrastructure and is required to have all the Spark Core's low-level services up and running before you can use the high-level APIs in Spark SQL (or Spark MLlib). Nothing has changed here.

```
scala> :type spark
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

scala> spark.sparkContext
res1: org.apache.spark.SparkContext = org.apache.spark.SparkContext@1e86506c
```